# How do I display a list of civicrm events on a separate wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, civievent

Our CiviCRM site is using Drupal but i have another site on a separate server that uses Wordpress that i want to display the event information with links to the other site for registration. I explored using a view to display RSS feeds and using a feeds plugin on the Wordpress site to propagate the info but that didn't seem like a very easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal Views + RSS feed solution sounds reasonable to me! There's lots of great support for generating RSS feeds in Drupal and we've had some good successes with that methodology.

Answer (score 1):

To display Drupal content on a Wordpress site, I've had good success with iFrames. The steps involve:

1. On the Drupal site, create the content that is to be displayed in the wordpress site, as a page -- usually with views, but it doesn't matter.
2. Create a Drupal theme suitable for iframe embedding, e.g. like this https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_iframe_theme
3. Use your favourite theme switcher module to use this iframe-friendly theme for your content (views) page.
4. Emebed that page in your wordpress site as an iframe.